# MML MathJax <mi mathvariant="double-struck"> Common HTML not displaying properly in iOS and Android mobile

Tags: mathjax

We are in the process of updating our MathJax rendering option from HTML-CSS to Common HTML. Using HTML-CSS we had no problems displaying our Maths content however with the new Common HTML configuration we now have character display issues in iOS and Android phones. I have attached an example of the code. Can anyone point out a potential problem in the MML. The problem can bee seen on this CodePen using iPhone 6 or Android http://codepen.io/Terminalpunk/pen/pyxPWV

[Here is an example image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSR63.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Working in Android and iOS</h2>
    <p>
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mover accent="true">
                                <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>γ</mi>
                                </mrow>
                            </mover>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi mathvariant="double-struck">G</mi>
                            <mo>+</mo>
                            <mi mathvariant="double-struck">B</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mtext>GLM</mtext>
                        </mrow>
                    </msubsup>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>.
    </p>

    <p>
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mover accent="true">
                            <mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi mathvariant="double-struck">ℙ</mi>
                                </mrow>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                        </mover>
                        <mi>i</mi>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msubsup>
                    <mo xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">=</mo>
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mover accent="true">
                                <mi>p</mi>
                                <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                            </mover>
                        </mrow>
                        <mi>i</mi>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msubsup>
                    <msub xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck">ℙ</mi>
                            </mrow>
                        </mrow>
                        <mn>0</mn>
                    </msub>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span> and
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mover accent="true">
                            <mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi mathvariant="double-struck">ℙ</mi>
                                </mrow>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                        </mover>
                        <mi>i</mi>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msubsup>
                    <mo xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">=</mo>
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mover accent="true">
                                <mi>p</mi>
                                <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                            </mover>
                        </mrow>
                        <mi>i</mi>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msubsup>
                    <msub xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck">ℙ</mi>
                            </mrow>
                        </mrow>
                        <mn>0</mn>
                    </msub>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>

    <h2>Not Working Android and iOS</h2>
    <p>
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msubsup xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                            <mi mathvariant="bold">γ</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo>+</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                        <mtext>GLM</mtext>
                    </msubsup>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msub xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mover accent="true">
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                        </mover>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>,
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msub xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mover accent="true">
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                        </mover>
                        <mrow>
                            <mspace width="thinmathspace"></mspace>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow></mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>,
        <span data-equation-construct="true" class="math-equation-construct">
            <span data-equation-mathml="true" class="math-equation-mathml">
                <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <msub xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mover accent="true">
                            <mrow>
                                <mi mathvariant="double-struck"></mi>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo stretchy="true">ˆ</mo>
                        </mover>
                        <mi mathvariant="normal">Z</mi>
                    </msub>
                </mml:math>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>

    <!-- This Works -->
    <!-- script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML"></script-->

    <!-- This doesn't work -->
    <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

An issue has been accepted on the MathJax library however a content fix to the MML has been provided [Git Hub Issue 1451](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1451)

> When you make a reference to a double-strick character like
>
> `<mi mathvariant="double-struck">&#x1D53D;</mi>`
> you are actually over-specifying the variant. The character  is already double-struck, so there should be no need to specify mathvariant="double-struck" in this case. The CommonHTML should still handle this situation correctly, but currently doesn't. What's happening is that MathJax doesn't actually find this character in its fonts and so makes a Unicode reference hoping that the character can be found in some font installed on your system. When you view this from a desktop machine, you apparently have fonts that do include these character positions (perhaps the STIX fonts?), and so the system can display them. Most mobile devices don't have fonts for these, so they are not being displayed there.
>
> The example that does work on the mobiles uses the double struck P, which is at ℙ, and it turns out that CommonHTML does properly recognize the characters in the Letterlike Symbols block where this one is found, so it is handled properly for you (but note the missing double-struck B and G in the equations including the P's). The reason that the double-struck B (and G) works in the initial equation is that you used
>
> `<mi mathvariant="double-struck">B</mi>` rather than using the Math Alphabet reference at .
>
> The CommonHTML output should translate the Math Alphabetic references to the proper locations in its own font, but it isn't currently doing so (the HTML-CSS and SVG output do, which is why it worked for you before). This should be fixed, but for now, you could use
>
> `<mi mathvariant="double-struck">F</mi>` rather than `<mi mathvariant="double-struck">&#x1D53D;</mi>`
>
> Answer supplied by [@dpvc](https://github.com/dpvc)